# Services fails to restart after reboot

Tags: vespa

Even after enabling vespa service on linux environment using systemctl enable vespa, the service fails to initialize as the service initialized before the network was ready and hence the service is not able to listen on the ports. Had to add dependency of Network in the /usr/lib/systemd/system/vespa.service by adding After=network.target  in the [Unit] section to start service only after initializing network. Can the service config files be enhanced to include this dependency. This had to be done after every vespa upgrade as the update overwrites the service config files

Vespa version information

Name        : vespa
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 7.83.27
Release     : 1.el7

Please include After=network.target in the [Unit] section of the service config files

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for making us aware of this. I have made the necessary changes here:
https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/pull/10157

The fix will be part of Vespa >= 7.87.x to be released next week.